# Check if String contains certain Number without CStr conversion - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to check if a number exists in a string using VBA? Say I have a number - `137785973201908000000000` - and it is in a cell formatted as Number, how do I convert it to a string to use the `InStr` function?

At the moment, if I use `CStr(number)` it will convert it to - `1.37785973201908E+23` - which is not ideal. The string I am trying to find the number in looks like this - [137785973201908000000000] Product Shipped.

When using `If InStr(stringVar, CStr(numberVar)) > 0 Then` it will not find the number because it is converting it to the scientific notation when converting to text.

Is there VBA coding that can stop this?

Comment: Do you expect 137785973201908000000001 being a valid input? Because it will be truncated if the input are formated as number in Excel. You might want to store the data as text from the start. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/269370/last-digits-are-changed-to-zeroes-when-you-type-long-numbers-in-cells.

Comment: +1 for storing your number as Text - Excel can only support 15 digits of precision, so if your number is larger than that you will lose information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Format$`.

```
If InStr(stringVar, Format$(numberVar, "0")) > 0
```

Comment: Format is another way to do this. Nice :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `CDec`. Is this what you want?

```
Debug.Print CDec(numbervar)
```

[image]